# How to find all combinations

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools

How do I go about finding all combinations of a string and a letter/number for example:
string = StackOverFlow
letter = Z
combinations:

```
SztackOverFlow
SztzackOverFlow
StzackOverFlow
```

and so on... I want all the combinations.

Another example:

string "Dumb"

letter "Z"

combinations:

```
DZumb
DZuZmb
DZuZmZb
DuZmZb
DumZb
```

I dont want the letter "Z" added to the end or front of the string "Dumb

I have tried using itertools, but I cant seem to figure it out with their documentation.

All the solutions I have seen are not what I am looking for.. it needs to produce the combinations i posted above..

Comment: @DYZ I don't think that dupe target is relevant.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by those combinations. How you want them to form. Help us help you.

Comment: @user2357112 How can I explain anymore lol? homework sheet? I need it to produce all combinations.. so for examples lets say I want the string "Dumb" and I want another letter "Z":
all combinations:
DZumb
DZuZmb
DZuZmZb
DuZmZb
DumZb

better explanation now? only one thing to add... I dont want the letter "Z" added to the end or front of the string "Dumb".

Comment: @VikashSingh edited post. Please re read. sorry about that.

Comment: Nope, still not enough. You have some nonstandard definition of "combination" in mind that you have not properly conveyed. Simply saying the word "combination" won't convey the definition you have in your head. While examples help, they are no substitute for an actual definition, especially since your example has some oddities that suggest that you got it wrong.

Comment: OK. So there are 3 slots in "Dumb" where "Z" can be inserted. That means there are `2**3=8` possible combinations.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for an actual response. Yes you are correct. and stack over flow is 2**12 = 4096 combinations. Now how would I go about creating a script in python that presents me all those combinations?

Comment: What about `'DuZmb', 'DZumZb'`?  Don't they count?

Comment: I'm reopening this question, not because I don't think it's probably a duplicate of a previous question, but because I don't think the dup target was very good -- there's a (tiny) bit more to this question than just knowing about itertools.product, and there are much better Cartesian product question targets if we really want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should get you what you want: [I will try to optimise it more]

```
def combination(word, letter, start=1, end=-1):
    if start >= end:
        return [word]
    else:
        new_word = word[:start] + letter + word[start:]
        output = [new_word, word]
        output.extend(combination(new_word, letter, start+2, end+1))
        output.extend(combination(word, letter, start+1, end))
        return list(set(output))
```

output:

```
combination('dumb', 'z', start=1, end=len('dumb'))

['dzuzmb', 'duzmb', 'dzuzmzb', 'dzumb', 'dzumzb', 'dumzb', 'dumb', 'duzmzb']
```

If you don't want the original word in the return list then you can go with this code:

```
def combination(word, letter, start=1, end=-1):
    if start >= end:
        return []
    else:
        new_word = word[:start] + letter + word[start:]
        output = [new_word]
        output.extend(combination(new_word, letter, start+2, end+1))
        output.extend(combination(word, letter, start+1, end))
        return list(set(output))
```

Explanation:

base of recursion is this:

```
 if start is >= end: return [No place left to insert letter in word]

 otherwise:
      insert letter at start of the word and call the same method to work on this new word from inserted index +2.

      *+2 because say at index 1 in dumb. We insert letter z as dzumd. Now we don't want to insert another z at dzzumb. So +2.*

      also in the original word just pass it into recursion because we want to work on duzmb. where no z is inserted before u.
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a generator that uses `itertools.product` to create the combinations of filled and unfilled slots and then zips them together with the letters of the word.

```
from itertools import product

def inserted(word, ch):
    n = len(word) - 1
    last = word[-1]
    patterns = product(('', ch), repeat=n)
    # skip the initial empty string pattern
    next(patterns)
    for t in patterns:
        yield ''.join([u+v for u,v in zip(word, t)]) + last

word = 'Dumb'
letter = 'Z'
for s in inserted(word, letter):
    print(s)
```

**output**

```
DumZb
DuZmb
DuZmZb
DZumb
DZumZb
DZuZmb
DZuZmZb
```

---

Just for fun, here's essentially the same algorithm, but using binary counting instead of `itertools.product`, so no imports are required.

```
def inserted(word, ch):
    n = len(word) - 1
    last = word[-1]
    t = ('', ch)
    for i in range(1, 2**n):
        yield ''.join([u + t[int(b)] 
            for b, u in zip('{:0{}b}'.format(i, n), word)]) + last
```

I think you'll agree that my first version is a little easier to read. :)

Comment: I was playing around with `[''.join(chain(*zip(word, p + ("",)))) for p in product(["","Z"], repeat=len(word)-1)]`..

Comment: @DSM Nice, and I guess it's not a big deal that it also includes the original word.